# Integrating Azure devops with github

Tags: azure-devops

I want to integrate git hub repository whom i was added as a collaborator to azure devops but while turning on the trigger the errors was coming "Unable to configure a service on the selected GitHub repository. This is likely caused by not having the necessary permission to manage hooks for the selected repository"

I know you can create a service connection to GitHub Enterprise using a PAT or oauth. The problem is it doesn't seem possible to scope the connection to a specific GHE organization or repository. If using a PAT, the connection will have the same visibility to repositories as the user and I believe it is the same with oath. I'm trying to limit the scope of repositories allowed over the connection. We default our repos open if you can authenticate but for some use cases, we would like to scope down access to a particular repository.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a minute to familiarize yourself with this site's FAQs https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. After that, you may edit your question or migrate it to  ServerFault https://serverfault.com/ as more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you just need **the admin for one particular repository** in github, instead of for whole organization. Refer to this [github help page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization#changing-repository-settings), just need **repository administrator** role thus you will has permission for **Manage webhooks, service hooks, and deploy keys**.

Contact your github organization owner or admin, let them go this particular repository that you want to integrated with Azure Devops, then click on Settings->Next to the your collaborator's name, choose the **Admin** permission level.

[image]

This admin permission level only give you the access scope of one particular repository instead of admin for other repositories included.

Comment: I won't be able to get that admin drop down to set the permissions for a particular repository. Could u please illustrate the same?

Comment: @ParasManchanda, this drop down can only be modified by the organization owner or admin. You'd better contact them.

Comment: @ParasManchanda Hi, what about this solution? Does the reos admin role could achieve what you want? If yes, you can [accept this answer thus it could help other SO users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/541930) who has the same issue with you. If still has any other issue, feel free to leave comment here. Then we could still help you.

Comment: Is there any other way we can scope the access of particular repository.Something like creating the web hooks? or any other way? If so how could we achieve it?

Comment: @ParasManchanda, Of course it has, but no matter how it is set, eventually, it need the repos admin setting. Because, it require doing operate to Github. Another work around is import the github repos into Devops repos, then build with Devops repos. Not recommend this because it will lose the automatic trigger from github. The second work around is why not fork the github repos into yours? Then connect yourself github into Azure Devops.